# "Something went wrong" ao criar projeto

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Criei um projeto android xamarin - o xml está como veio, não escrevi nenhuma linha em nada ainda, mas não consigo ver o design:

[image: screenshot de erro no visual studio]

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPlatformPkgInfo.getLibsFromJson(LocalPlatformPkgInfo.java:402)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPlatformPkgInfo.getOptionalLibraries(LocalPlatformPkgInfo.java:384)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPlatformPkgInfo.createAndroidTarget(LocalPlatformPkgInfo.java:251)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPlatformPkgInfo.getAndroidTarget(LocalPlatformPkgInfo.java:104)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalSdk.getTargets(LocalSdk.java:712)
>       at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.getTargets(SdkManager.java:181)
>       at mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.getAndroidTarget(AndroidDesignerHost.java:87)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.initialize(DesignerSession.java:107)
>       at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:401)
>       at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:432)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:45)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
>       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:338)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
>       ... 14 more

Comment: cadê seu código?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa da versão 64bits do java instalada.
Além disso, atualize a versão do Xamarin. 
Instale a Api 25 do Android, Build Tool 25.0.x e o Platform-tools 25.0.x

(Note que pode haver atualizações dessas tools)

Esse tipo de erro é referente a versões de Build Tools do Android.

(Retirado do Post do Montemagno)
http://motzcod.es/post/157589380047/xamarin-cycle-9-preparing-machines